# Sort By Column A Not Working Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I'm trying to sort by column A from range A2-A30000 and I want to make the drop down on Column A Row 1 but it is neither sorting or enabling the dropdown on Column A Row 1. Even without VBA when I just select the A1 and press filter it automatically ends up putting the dropdown on A2. Another problem that occurs is that it only sorts column A but just moves column A around but leaves the other columns alone making the entire worksheet wrong.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A2:A30000")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: You need to select all of your columns in you worksheet to filter and sort them all

Comment: For Sort, you need to set the `SetRange` with the range of your whole table. For filter, I recommend you see the `Worksheets.AutoFilter` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A2:BZ30000")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1):

You are only referencing column A; use the .CurrentRegion property to isolate the data 'island' radiating out to the first completely blank row and completely blank column. I suspect you have a text column label in A1.

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    With .Cells(1, "A").CurrentRegion
        .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
    End With
End With
```

The recorded code works fine in some instances but sorting can be handled by VBA functionality more efficiently.

You really should know whether you have a header or not; never use xlGuess.